# Trying to use jQuery.load() to upload http:// file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load html page from  server into another page on the same server, using jquery.load() method.
 This is the code:

```
<div id="mydiv">
<script type="text/javascript" >
 $('#mydiv').load('http://www.myurl.com/ns/pagename.html');
</script>
</div>
```

It's not loading... I tested it locally, loading it on side other page and it was fine...Also html page works fine by itself...
What am I doing wrong??

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: For clarification the HTML page you are attempting to load is on the same domain, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#mydiv').load('/ns/pagename.html body');
</script>
```

Make the request after the div is added to the DOM, request a relative URL and grab just the body.

Comment: in  Console I have an errror"NetworkError: 404 Not Found" pointing to the html file...

Comment: <div id="mydiv"></div>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#mydiv').load('/ns/pagename.html body');
</script>    Not working....

Comment: "404 Not Found" Then the URL is wrong. Note the space before `body`. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: The path is correct, if I paste url in the browser, it works fine, but it does not show content in the page when I try to use .load(), loading same url. Those two files are in the different servers so. Could it be a problem?